# Using columns of different data types to create a conditional column

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, directquery

I want to create a conditional column using DAX, which compares 2 date columns and a status column that derives a condition.

I have tried this code:

```
Status of Feedback =
IF (
    ISBLANK ( 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[ProcConfm_CompdDate] )
        || 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[DatePlus20] > 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[Present Day]
            && ISBLANK ( 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[ProcsAccptce_Status] ),
    "Audit<20days",
    0
)
```

But I am getting the following error:  **Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns.**

Is there any way I can achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an `IF` block that for `TRUE` yields one data type (e.g. `STRING`) and for `FALSE` yields another (e.g. `INTEGER`) - this is what is referred to in the error as expressions that **`yield variant data-type`**. In other words, the problem is not the columns you are using in your condition statement, but what you have assigned to be the output of this function.

Try this:

```
Status of Feedback =
IF (
    ISBLANK ( 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[ProcConfm_CompdDate] )
        || 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[DatePlus20] > 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[Present Day]
            && ISBLANK ( 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[ProcsAccptce_Status] ),
    "Audit<20days",
    "0"
)
```

Or leave out the `FALSE` block entirely:

```
Status of Feedback =
IF (
    ISBLANK ( 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[ProcConfm_CompdDate] )
        || 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[DatePlus20] > 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[Present Day]
            && ISBLANK ( 'DAT IndAudPlan_IntSys_FindgMgmt_Findgs_RA_5Whys'[ProcsAccptce_Status] ),
    "Audit<20days"
)
```